# comma separated server side searching datatable

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, datatables, server-side

I have implemented server side searching using datatable for single keyword like as shown in **[Server-side processing](https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side)**. For single keyword the server-side searching is working fine. but now the problem is that I got a requirement to search keywords by comma seperated like `Accountant, Garrett, Tokyo` etc

I am using MySQL datatabse, and Java as Backhand

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: this question lacks a ton of detail.  which database are you using? is this a form post? php?

Comment: @bart2puck sorry for that, I am using MySQL datatabse, and Java as Backhand. I like to search with multiple keywords using comma separated in jquery datatable

Comment: use mysql REGEX to achieve this

Comment: @MayankPandeyz can we search the comma seperated kewords on all columns using REGEX, can you give me a example

Comment: Google it with "comma separated keywords on all columns using REGEX"

Answer (score 0):

[SELECT IN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

You can use SELECT IN in mysql.(link for tutorial above)  I do not know the syntax for java but you need to loop through your search values.

```
 "SELECT * From table WHERE someField IN ( 'Accountant', 'Garrett', 'Tokyo');
```

replace those values in the parenthesis with variables and you will have what you are looking for.

Comment: but I cant serach the  ``'Accountant', 'Garrett', 'Tokyo'` on all columns using IN

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Whatever query you are using for single entry will work the same as this one, just change the syntax to above.